# cannot override post_types in WP_Query()

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I'm creating a featured post slider which takes 4 pages or posts from the 'featured' category.  I'm trying to use WP_Query, but am having no joy :(

my slider query is:

```
$ml_featured = new WP_Query( 

    array(
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'post_type' => array('page', 'post'),
        'category__in' => 22
    )
);


if( $ml_featured->have_posts() ) {
    while( have_posts() ) : $ml_featured->the_post();

        // looping

    endwhile;
}
else {
    // no posts
}
```

fire_PHP shows the WP_Query contains:

```
WP_Query(
    query =
    array(
        ['posts_per_page'] => 4
        ['post_type'] =>
            array(
                [0] => 'page'
                [1] => 'post'
            )
        ['category__in'] => 22
    )

    query_vars =
    array(

        ['posts_per_page'] => 4
        ['post_type'] =>
            array(
                [0] => 'wod'
                [1] => 'attachment'
            )
        ['category__in'] =>
            array(
                [0] => 22
            )
```

I'm using Genesis, building upon the sample child theme.  In order to display my custom post type 'WOD' on the homepage I've added to functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'ml_wods_home' );
function ml_wods_home( $query ) {

    if ( is_home() && false == $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'wod', 'attachment' ) );

    return $query;
}
```

as suggested at [Justin Tadlock](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/02/02/showing-custom-post-types-on-your-home-blog-page).  This works well on its own, but seems to be interfering with the slider query:

Please note that query['post_type'] is overwritten by query_vars['post_type'].  In addition, the browser is timing out frequently as I mess around...

I found that [Michael Fields had a related issue](http://wordpress.mfields.org/2010/getting-down-and-dirty-with-wp_query-set/) , posted a solution, (which I think I'm implementing) but its not working for me, and I don't understand it..

What am I missing?!  TIA, Tim

Comment: I guess your condition fails...

Comment: Hi Rutwick, are you referring to the condition in ml_wods_home()? this runs fine, but I think it interferes with the feature-slider.. i'll clarify the question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all,`while( have_posts()):` should be `while( $ml_featured->have_posts()):`

And secondly, in your `pre_get_posts` callback you check:

```
false == $query->query_vars['suppress_filters']
```

But this returns true for every `WP_Query` query and any `get_posts` query where 'supress_filters' is explicitly set to false. If you want to check if the query is the 'main' query (i.e. query associated with the global `$wp_query`), you can use:

```
$query->is_main_query();
```

([see documentation here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_query)). This returns true if `$query` is the main query and false otherwise. **This function was introduced in 3.3**. Before 3.3 you can *probably* check (untested):

```
global $wp_the_query;
if($query === $wp_the_query){
  //is main query
}else{
  // is not main query
}
```

Alternatively (but preferably use the methods above), to alter the **main** query only:

```
 global $wp_query;
 $wp_query->set( 'post_type', array( 'wod', 'attachment' ) );
```

Comment: oh, man - all the options - thanks a million I was going mad!